# Cognos Multipage Bursting

Tags: cognos

i have a cognos report that consists of 3 pages , each page has different information coming from a different query . i dont have a what you call a master query that joins the data for all 3 pages .

the 3 pages have a common field that is email . i need to set up bursting such that each email in each page , receives the information that is on that page related to that email .

i ran into a problem where i can only set up one bursting group query . while i have 3 .

is there any option that i can use that doesnt require me to make a summary query of all 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to implement page sets creating a master-detail relationship so that each page is sliced per email.  This can be done outside of burst and can be easily validated using the page down.   You should see email1 P1, email1 P2, email1, P3 then email2 P1, email2 P2 ....

Once that is in place.  You can tie your burst query to the pageSet, which should give you what you are looking for.

```xml
<report xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/16.2/" useStyleVersion="11.6" expressionLocale="en">
    <drillBehavior/>
    <layouts>
        <layout>
            <reportPages>
                <pageSet name="Page set1" refQuery="PageSet">
                    <detailPages>
                        <page name="Page1">
                            <style>
                                <defaultStyles>
                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="pg"/>
                                </defaultStyles>
                            </style>
                            <pageBody>
                                <style>
                                    <defaultStyles>
                                        <defaultStyle refStyle="pb"/>
                                    </defaultStyles>
                                </style>
                                <contents>
                                    <list horizontalPagination="true" name="List1" refQuery="Query1">
                                        <noDataHandler>
                                            <contents>
                                                <block>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <staticValue>No Data Available</staticValue>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <CSS value="padding:16px;"/>
                                                    </style>
                                                </block>
                                            </contents>
                                        </noDataHandler>
                                        <style>
                                            <CSS value="border-collapse:collapse"/>
                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="ls"/>
                                            </defaultStyles>
                                        </style>
                                        <listColumns>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Product line"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Product line"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Unit sale price"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lm"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Unit sale price"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                        </listColumns>
                                        <masterDetailLinks>
                                            <masterDetailLink>
                                                <masterContext>
                                                    <dataItemContext refDataItem="Product line"/>
                                                </masterContext>
                                                <detailContext>
                                                    <dataItemContext refDataItem="Product line"/>
                                                </detailContext>
                                            </masterDetailLink>
                                        </masterDetailLinks>
                                    </list>
                                </contents>
                            </pageBody>
                            <XMLAttributes>
                                <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_legacyDrillDown" value="0"/>
                            </XMLAttributes>
                        </page>
                        <page name="Page2">
                            <pageBody>
                                <contents>
                                    <crosstab horizontalPagination="true" name="Crosstab2" refQuery="Query2">
                                        <crosstabCorner>
                                            <contents>
                                                <textItem>
                                                    <dataSource>
                                                        <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Quantity"/>
                                                    </dataSource>
                                                </textItem>
                                            </contents>
                                            <style>
                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="xm"/>
                                                </defaultStyles>
                                            </style>
                                        </crosstabCorner>
                                        <noDataHandler>
                                            <contents>
                                                <block>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <staticValue>No Data Available</staticValue>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <CSS value="padding:16px;"/>
                                                    </style>
                                                </block>
                                            </contents>
                                        </noDataHandler>
                                        <style>
                                            <CSS value="border-collapse:collapse"/>
                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="xt"/>
                                            </defaultStyles>
                                        </style>
                                        <crosstabRows>
                                            <crosstabNode>
                                                <crosstabNodeMembers>
                                                    <crosstabNodeMember refDataItem="Product line">
                                                        <style>
                                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="ml"/>
                                                            </defaultStyles>
                                                        </style>
                                                        <contents>
                                                            <textItem>
                                                                <dataSource>
                                                                    <memberCaption/>
                                                                </dataSource>
                                                            </textItem>
                                                        </contents>
                                                    </crosstabNodeMember>
                                                </crosstabNodeMembers>
                                            </crosstabNode>
                                        </crosstabRows>
                                        <defaultMeasure refDataItem="Quantity"/>
                                        <crosstabFactCell>
                                            <contents>
                                                <textItem>
                                                    <dataSource>
                                                        <cellValue/>
                                                    </dataSource>
                                                </textItem>
                                            </contents>
                                            <style>
                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="mv"/>
                                                </defaultStyles>
                                            </style>
                                        </crosstabFactCell>
                                        <crosstabColumns>
                                            <crosstabNode>
                                                <crosstabNodeMembers>
                                                    <crosstabNodeMember refDataItem="Year">
                                                        <style>
                                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="ml"/>
                                                            </defaultStyles>
                                                        </style>
                                                        <contents>
                                                            <textItem>
                                                                <dataSource>
                                                                    <memberCaption/>
                                                                </dataSource>
                                                            </textItem>
                                                        </contents>
                                                    </crosstabNodeMember>
                                                </crosstabNodeMembers>
                                            </crosstabNode>
                                        </crosstabColumns>
                                        <masterDetailLinks>
                                            <masterDetailLink>
                                                <masterContext>
                                                    <dataItemContext refDataItem="Product line"/>
                                                </masterContext>
                                                <detailContext>
                                                    <dataItemContext refDataItem="Product line"/>
                                                </detailContext>
                                            </masterDetailLink>
                                        </masterDetailLinks>
                                    </crosstab>
                                </contents>
                                <style>
                                    <defaultStyles>
                                        <defaultStyle refStyle="pb"/>
                                    </defaultStyles>
                                </style>
                            </pageBody>
                            <style>
                                <defaultStyles>
                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="pg"/>
                                </defaultStyles>
                            </style>
                        </page>
                        <page name="Page3">
                            <pageBody>
                                <contents>
                                    <list horizontalPagination="true" name="List2" refQuery="Query3">
                                        <noDataHandler>
                                            <contents>
                                                <block>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <staticValue>No Data Available</staticValue>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <CSS value="padding:16px;"/>
                                                    </style>
                                                </block>
                                            </contents>
                                        </noDataHandler>
                                        <style>
                                            <CSS value="border-collapse:collapse"/>
                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="ls"/>
                                            </defaultStyles>
                                        </style>
                                        <listColumns>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Product line"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Product line"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Order method type"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <textItem>
                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Order method type"/>
                                                            </dataSource>
                                                        </textItem>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                        </listColumns>
                                        <masterDetailLinks>
                                            <masterDetailLink>
                                                <masterContext>
                                                    <dataItemContext refDataItem="Product line"/>
                                                </masterContext>
                                                <detailContext>
                                                    <dataItemContext refDataItem="Product line"/>
                                                </detailContext>
                                            </masterDetailLink>
                                        </masterDetailLinks>
                                    </list>
                                </contents>
                                <style>
                                    <defaultStyles>
                                        <defaultStyle refStyle="pb"/>
                                    </defaultStyles>
                                </style>
                            </pageBody>
                            <style>
                                <defaultStyles>
                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="pg"/>
                                </defaultStyles>
                            </style>
                        </page>
                    </detailPages>
                </pageSet>
            </reportPages>
        </layout>
    </layouts>
    <XMLAttributes>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_CreateExtendedDataItems" value="true"/>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="listSeparator" value=","/>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="decimalSeparator" value="."/>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_modelModificationTime" value="2013-01-08T15:32:22.123Z"/>
    </XMLAttributes>
    <queries>
        <query name="PageSet">
            <source>
                <model/>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Product line">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Products].[Product line]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
        </query>
        <query name="Query1">
            <source>
                <model/>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Product line">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Products].[Product line]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="average" name="Unit sale price">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales].[Unit sale price]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="2"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="2"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
        </query>
        <query name="Query2">
            <source>
                <model/>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Product line">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Products].[Product line]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="total" name="Quantity">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales].[Quantity]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="1"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="2"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Year">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Time].[Year]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="1"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
        </query>
        <query name="Query3">
            <source>
                <model/>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Product line">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Products].[Product line]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Order method type">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Order method].[Order method type]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
        </query>
    </queries>
    <modelPath>/content/folder[@name=&apos;Samples_DQ&apos;]/folder[@name=&apos;Models&apos;]/package[@name=&apos;GO Sales (query)&apos;]/model[@name=&apos;model&apos;]</modelPath>
</report>
```

Comment: Above is a spec which does the page sets,  you just need to add the burst to it.

Comment: thanks alot :D , one more question i see you use things in the subpages queries that are not present in the  pageset query . what are the constraints around that ?

Comment: Very welcome!   In theory this is like a chain effect,  the page set query only needs the items that drive the pages.  When you put the burst query on top of that it would drive the page set query which in turn would drive the detail pages.

If you end up with a CRX error just post it, this is usually fixed by using the properties property, but we can cross that bridge if and or when we get to it.